# Using device's camera as background for Android OpenGL ES Java application

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, camera

I am developing an application which I want to use the device's camera as the background for a OpenGL ES Java application.I am new to OpenGL ES and this is one of my first apps.

A quick answer would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use opencv. You can get frames and set them as texture

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Look at VideoCapture class

Comment: I am developing a Java Android app , not C++.Also Android already has a video / image capture API

Comment: And then wha is the question? You can set frames of video of background as a texture of some plane. Set size of this plane and texture according to z-coordinate of it, so you get both space for you scene and multisapmling of you texture

Comment: I want to have the background of my OpenGL ES Android app to be the device's camera